# How to extract values in string by using Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string which looks like:

> (Service=[MyCar]&(Type=[News]|Type=[Review]))

I need to get the values of Type, there could be 1 type or multiple types.

My current regular expression is:

```
/Type=[(News|Review|Video)]*/g
```

It doesn't return me the values, instead it returns "Type="

Comment: how about `/Type=\[(\w+)\]/`?

Comment: @miao it works as well :) thanks

Comment: Hi @miao it works as well, but it returns "Type=[News]" rather "News"

Answer (score 2):

The square brackets `[]` have a special meaning in regex, so they need to be escaped:

```
Type=\[(News|Review|Video)\]
```

Compare [this](https://regex101.com/r/pS9lJ8/1)

With [this](https://regex101.com/r/pS9lJ8/2)

In the first case you are actually matching a single character in the list `(News|RviVdo)` with `[(News|Review|Video)]`

For each match, you will find the text you are looking for in `Group[1]`

Comment: Hi there, I tried in C#, it returns Type=[News], but I want News

Comment: @Franva: `News` will be in your capture group.

Comment: @CinCout What are you talking about? The regex is in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `MatchCollection` and prefix brackets `[]` with a backslash `\`

```
        string input = "(Service=[MyCar]&(Type=[News]|Type=[Review]))";

        string pattern = @"Type=\[(News|Review|Video)\]";

        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
        foreach(Match match in matches)
        {
            foreach(Group group in match.Groups)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(group);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's odd, it doesn't yield any results for me in C#, but it did when I tried it online.

Comment: I found that I had extra "/g" which made this not worked. However, it returns Type=[News] as value, I expect News as value

Comment: @Franva `MatchCollection` is a `Collection` of `Match`. I used a `nested foreach` to demonstrate this. You have several options to extract the results you want. Look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

A pattern like this

> Type=[(\w*)]

will give you the groups. You can look at the expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/tW2oD4/1). Also you can test this C# code at [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tqwTai)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "(Service=[CarSales]&(Type=[News]|Type=[Review]))";

        string pattern = @"Type=\[(\w*)\]";

        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);


        foreach(Match match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
        }


    }
}
```

You can find some information about the groups and the index on the MSDN "Match.Groups Property" page.